# Issue with react-sound state management

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having some trouble with state management in react-sound. I have a dynamic grid of buttons - when mousing over a button, audio plays as an example of what that button represents, and when mousing off, it stops. Right now, it's running into problems when you click on a button and the screen reloads another array as a grid of buttons - when you do that and then navigate back to the former screen, the behavior is REVERSED, so that audio plays when you mouse OFF the button and stops when you mouse ON. I've tried several things that I thought should work, including triggering toggleHoverState() on click, but nothing has worked so far. Any advice? Code below:

```
class Screen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {displayArray: taxonomyArray,
    isHovering: false};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseHover = this.handleMouseHover.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseHover() {
    this.setState(this.toggleHoverState);
  }

  toggleHoverState(state) {
    return {
      isHovering: !state.isHovering,
    };
  }

  handleClick(updatedArray = taxonomyArray) {
    //this.setState(this.toggleHoverState);
    this.setState({
      displayArray: updatedArray,
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      this.state.displayArray.map(item =>
        <Col key={Math.random()} span={4} xs="auto" sm="auto" md="auto" lg="auto">
          <a key={Math.random()} data-tip={item.description ? (item.description) : console.log('null description')}>
            { (item.audio && this.state.isHovering) && <div><Sound url={item.audio} playStatus={Sound.status.PLAYING} volume={50}/></div> }
            <Button 
              className='trigger'
              key={Math.random()} 
              variant= {item.child === undefined ? "outline-secondary" : (item.child === null ? "secondary" : "primary") }
              onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
              onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
              onClick={ () => ( item.child === null ? console.log('nope') : ( item.child === undefined ? this.handleClick(arrayVisits.pop()) : (arrayVisits.push(this.state.displayArray), this.handleClick(item.child))) ) }
              >
                {item.name}
            </Button>   
          </a>    
          <ReactTooltip className='extraClass' delayHide={0} effect='solid' type="info" multiline={true}/>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </Col>
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic here is very strange:

```js
  handleMouseHover() {
    this.setState(this.toggleHoverState);
  }

  toggleHoverState(state) {
    return {
      isHovering: !state.isHovering,
    };
  }
```

Why not just write

```
  handleMouseHover() {
    this.setState({ isHovering: !this.state.isHovering })
  }
```

But if you're still having problems, I would write some very explicit functions for `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to reduce confusion:

```js
onMouseEnter={ () => { this.setState( isHovering: true ) } }

onMouseLeave={ () => { this.setState( isHovering: false) } }
```

Let me know if that solves it

Comment: This fixed the problem! I had to wrap the "isHovering: w/e" in curly brackets, but this did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the page actually reloading, or is it a BrowserRouter?

It sounds like, if it's a BrowserRouter, that state isn't being reset. Try adding:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.setState({isHovering:false})
}
```